# use variable as column name in where clause in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I want to use a variable as column name in my SQL query.

**Problem:**

I can not use dynamic SQL as the SQL query that I have is inside of a `user defined inline table function.`

What are other possible alternatives?

My code is as follows:

```
create function MatchStringPercent(@parameterFromUser nvarchar(20), @parameterInTable nvarchar(20))
RETURNS table As Return 
SELECT Top(1)
cast(LEN(@parameterInTable) as float)/(Abs(LEN(@parameterFromUser) - LEN(@parameterInTable)) + LEN(@parameterInTable))* 100 As Match
FROM Demo
WHERE @parameterInTable = LEFT( @parameterFromUser , LEN(@parameterInTable) )    --Problem here
ORDER BY LEN(@parameterInTable) DESC 
Go
```

Comment: If the column name is passed via a parameter then you have to use dynamic SQL and you can't use a function.

Comment: @bluefeet and dynamic SQL does not work inside of a function. Well, there must be some way to do it. I can't make it a stored procedure as it is to be called from a user defined function only.

Comment: @Simrankaur Then no, there isn't a way to do it, as simple as that

Comment: @Simrankaur If you can't use a stored procedure and you can't use dynamic SQL because you have to use a function, then I believe you might be out of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to do that, but the columns you are searching on must be all the same data type. The "trick" involves using a sort of UNPIVOT with CROSS APPLY VALUES.

Here's an example:

```
-- Go to a safe place to work on
USE tempdb;
GO

-- Drop sample data if exists
IF OBJECT_ID('Demo') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE Demo;

-- Demo table
CREATE TABLE Demo (
    pk   varchar(50) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    col2 varchar(50),
    col3 varchar(50),
    col4 varchar(50)
)
GO

-- Some sample values
INSERT INTO Demo VALUES
 ('aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd')
,('eee','fff','ggg','hhh')
,('iii','jjj','kkk','lll')
,('mmm','nnn','ooo','ppp')
,('qqq','rrr','sss','ttt')
,('www','xxx','yyy','zzz');
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('MatchStringPercent') IS NULL
    EXEC('CREATE FUNCTION MatchStringPercent() RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN SELECT 1 AS One')
GO

ALTER FUNCTION MatchStringPercent (
     @parameterFromUser NVARCHAR(20)
    ,@parameterInTable NVARCHAR(20)
    )
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN

SELECT TOP (1) CAST(LEN(@parameterInTable) AS FLOAT) / (ABS(LEN(@parameterFromUser) - LEN(@parameterInTable)) + LEN(@parameterInTable)) * 100 AS Match
FROM Demo AS d
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES
         (pk, 'col2', col2)
        ,(pk, 'col3', col3)
        ,(pk, 'col4', col4)
) AS v (pk, col, value)
WHERE v.col = @parameterInTable
    AND v.value = LEFT(@parameterFromUser, LEN(value)) 
ORDER BY LEN(value) DESC
GO


-- Test
SELECT *
FROM MatchStringPercent('ggg','col3')
```

Comment: @Simran kaur, be aware that this technique will require a full table scan.

Comment: @Dan Guzman true that. The search predicate wasn't sargable anyway, so I don't think it makes a huge difference.

Comment: Don't you want v.value in the calculated match ? SELECT TOP (1) CAST(LEN(v.value) AS FLOAT) / (ABS(LEN(@parameterFromUser) - LEN(v.value)) + LEN(v.value)) * 100 AS Match